# Having trouble in solving unmet dpeendencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have been having difficulties in updating npm packages as part of upgrade. I see angular/core has unmet dependencies as shown below. I want to understand what does **'+',  '-',    ' ` '** mean?

Command I ran to see unmet depencencies : npm list @angular/core.
Also If please suggest me good documentation to read about the npm outputs like this.

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@8.2.14
`-- adal-angular5@1.0.36
  `-- @angular/core@5.2.11

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@6.1.10, required by @angular/http@6.1.10
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by angular-file-uploader@4.2.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0, required by codelyzer@4.3.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@4.0.0-rc.1, required by jasmine-angular-snapshot-testing@1.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by ng-feedback@1.1.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@>=4.3.0 <8.0.0, required by ngx-country-picker@1.4.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^5.0.0, required by ngx-ip@1.1.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by ngx-spinner@6.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In NPM you have to install peer dependencies by yourself.
If you don't do it, you get this message UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY nameOfThePackageWithUnmetPeerDep:

How to fix it?

```
npm install nameOfThePackageWithUnmetPeerDep
```

Sometimes, also deleting the node modules folder and doing *npm i* afterwards helps. Sometimes, also using npm prune might work.

Comment: Hi @GBra, thanks I also want to understand what does '+', '-' and ` characters in the output of npm list as shown in the question

Comment: +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@8.2.14
`-- adal-angular5@1.0.36
  `-- @angular/core@5.2.11

Comment: I think that those characters might depend on how the error was structured to be logged in the console. I believe It also looks different in different OS